# Binding two data frames

Tags: r

I'm trying to merging two data frames I have, the other is a long list of numbers from 1 to 6 (A) and the other is a vector with numbers 1 to 6 and name to each number (B).
How do I merge B to A so that the list of numbers in A will have the names of the corresponding numbers in B?

Best regards,
Hlynur T

Comment: Please provide some example data.

Comment: To add to Sven's request:  it makes a difference how exactly you've assigned names to each number --  `rownames`, `colnames`, list names, etc.

Comment: The list of numbers could be written as A <- sample(1:6,200,replace=T). And B was made by using (name <- c("A","B","C","D","E","F") and number <- 1:6) and B <- data.frame(name,number)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use match(). Say you have the following two data frames:

```
A <- data.frame(num=sample(1:6,100,replace=TRUE))
B <- data.frame(num=1:6,myname=letters[1:6])
```

Then to make a new column "myname" for the data frame A:

```
A[,'myname'] <- B[match(A[,'num'],B[,'num']),'myname']
```

As others mentioned, things change slightly if you used rownames() instead of creating a column for the names, but this general construction should work with a few tweaks regardless of the specifics.

Answer (score 2):

If this replicates your situation then `merge` is ht answer:

```
 dfB <- data.frame(numb = 1:6, nams = LETTERS[1:6])
 dfA <- data.frame(nums = sample(1:6, 30, repl=TRUE))
 merge(dfA, dfB, by.x="nums", by.y="numb")
```

(And this mus have been asked and answered a bunch of times in the past.)